# continue and break with an extended scope

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a possibility for a `continue` or `break` to have a bigger scope than the currently running loop?
In the following example, I desire to to continue on the outer for-loop when `expr` is true, although it is called in the inner for-loop, so that neither `[some inner code]` nor `[some outer code]` is executed.

```
for(int outerCounter=0;outerCounter<20;outerCounter++){
   for(int innerCounter=0;innerCounter<20;innerCounter++){
      if(expr){
         [continue outer];    // here I wish to continue on the outer loop     
      }
      [some inner  code]
   }
   [some outer code]
}
```

In the above

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `goto` if you absolutely must. However, I typically take one of two approaches:

- Make the inner loop a separate method returning `bool`, so I can just return from it and indicate what the outer loop should do (break, continue, or do the rest of the loop body)
- Keep a separate `bool` flag which is set before the inner loop, may be modified *within* the inner loop, and then is checked *after* the inner loop

Of these approaches I *generally* prefer the "extract method" approach.

Comment: It is amazing how communication skills can make the difference sometimes. I actually prefer your answer over my own.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean something like this?

```
for(int outerCounter=0;outerCounter<20;outerCounter++){
   for(int innerCounter=0;innerCounter<20;innerCounter++){
      if(expr){
         runOuter = true;
         break; 
      }
      [some inner  code]
   }
   if (!runOuter) {
      [some outer code]
   }
   runOuter = false;
}
```

Comment: It won't since runOuter will be true and [some outer code] runs only if runOuter is false. Isn't this the logic you wanted?

Comment: +1 Yes thanks, this is the second version of Jon Skeets post. However my previous comment was related to your first answer which did not solve the problem. I have deleted my comment.

Comment: @HCL, I just realized that. It's weird you were able to see that post since I tried to quickly delete it when I realized my mistake and the post a better answer. Anyway, Jon fully deserves this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use goto statement, otherwise - no, break and continue statements doesn't support this.

Although goto statement is considered as bad practice this is the only why to exit more than one for loops ... And it looks like this is the reason to be still a part of .NET

Answer (score 1):

You can use `goto` statement with labels:

```
   for(int outerCounter=0;outerCounter<20;outerCounter++){
      for(int innerCounter=0;innerCounter<20;innerCounter++){
         if(expr){
            break; 
         }
         [some inner  code]
      }
      // You will come here after break
      [some outer code]
   }
```