# C# for continue inside foreach

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach, continue

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [continue and break with an extended scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992810/continue-and-break-with-an-extended-scope)

i have one problem. I don't know how to call continue for "for" inside foreach.

Code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ...; i++)
{
  foreach(´´ .. in ´´)
  {
    if(,,.Value == null)
      // A!
  }
}
```

And i need replace "A!" for code to continue "for"! Not foreach. I used basic continue but it work just only for foreach.

SOLVED
with:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ...; i++)
{
  bool Ab = false;

  foreach(´´ .. in ´´)
  {
    if(,,.Value == null)
      Ab = true;
  }

  if(Ab)
    continue;
}
```

Comment: What sort of object are you looping through?  There might be a far better way than using the foreach... if... anti-pattern.

Comment: You can't, you need to use a variable to pass that information out to the for loop. As an aside, you'll get better responses if you accept some answers.

Comment: Try `break` instead of continue in your foreach loop, this will cause the execution to fall out of the `foreach` and continue the `for` loop

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982595/how-to-break-out-of-2-loops-without-a-flag-variable-in-c) could be the (probably unsatisfying) answer.

Answer (score 3):

if you need to stop the inner loop, and continue the outer loop, you just need a break statement in the inner loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < ...; i++)
{   
    foreach(var thing in something)   
    {     
        if(thing.Value == null)       
        {
            break; 
        } 
    }
```

}

Comment: but how i can call continue on break? Is any "if" on this?

Comment: the `break' statement stops the inner loop (what you want) and then continues the outer loop (what you want), so i'm not sure what more you need. If you have some specific need that this doesn't work, you need to post more code in your question so we know exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If that is your actual code structure, you can `break` from the `foreach` and the `for` will immediately continue to the next iteration because the current one is over.

If, however, you have more code in the `for` iteration after the completion of the `foreach` loop, you may be in one of those *rare* cases where (mothers, shield your child's ears) you *might* want to use a `goto` to skip to the end of the current `for` iteration.

The cleaner way, though, would be to fashion your internal loop so that it occurs at the end of your outer loop, such that a `break` in the internal loop is a `continue` of the outer loop.

Comment: *Pouring water on my burning ears*. Yeah, they give you the `goto` command because they know if they didn't, then someone, somewhere would come up with a situation that simply could not be solved any other way. But, the last paragraph is the "teaching answer"; the one that should be given to someone trying to learn how to code right. Use of `goto` is a very stinky code smell, anytime, anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just `break` the inner `foreach` loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i < blah; i++) {
  foreach (var item in collection) {
    if (ShouldContinue(item)) {
      break;
    }
    // other stuff
  }
  // don't put things here
}
```

If you need code where I put `don't put things here` it's probably far clearer if you wrap your inner loop in a function:

```
bool ProcessOrContinue(IEnumerable collection) {
  foreach (var item in collection) {
    if (ShouldContinue(item)) {
      return true;
    }
    // other stuff
  }
  return false;
}

for (int i = 0; i < blah; i++) {
  if (ProcessOrContinue(collection)) continue;
  // more things
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Continue` is a fancy goto. You could make use of recursion here instead.